# Error exporting PHP string into a file

Tags: php, file, slash

I have a website, where the user can write PHP/HTML code and save it to his computer. Everything is fine until the user types a slash (/).

The file saves into the client computer, but instead of saving the client code, it exports an PHP error (the file in the computer has a PHP code of an error). The file-saving code is the following:

```
$content = $_REQUEST['code'];   //Get the code

$file = "file.php";
file_put_contents($file, $content); //Writes the content into a file

header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file');
readfile(dirname(dirname($con)) . '/'.$file);
```

The error only happens when the client uses slashes. 
Any idea on why is this happening? )-:

EDIT:

This is one of those errors:

[image]

The code that i tried to export was the following:

```
/:
```

The thing that worries me, is that if I type exactly the same characters in different order (:/) then they export to my computer with no errors.

Comment: Is that your actual code? You have a typo on your second header. Look at your quotes.

Comment: Use a function to replace `/` with an `_`, right at the gate. Plus that missing quote as `BIOS` stated in `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file);`

Comment: Sorry, you're right, i was missing the quote. That's the actual code, but accidentally I erase the quote mark posting the code. Error posted!!! help me please.

Comment: Your error suggest that you have problem with `readfile(\/105.2.php)` in line 24 (path with '\' and '/' ?!). Is `readfile(dirname(dirname($con)) . '/'.$file);` in line 24 ? Put `print_r($con);` before `readfile()` and show us result.

Comment: Since the client is working with HTML/PHP code, if I print_r the code it displays the HTML result of the same code. But, if I print_r the example I mentioned before (/:) the result is /: ... it prints how it is supposed to export.

And yes, the readfile() is in line 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see only one error - problem with `readfile(\/105.2.php)` in line 24 - so I tested it.

```
$file = 'file.php';
$con = '/:';
readfile(dirname(dirname($con)) . '/'.$file);
```

It gives me incorrect path `\/file.php` as in error message.

If I use `$con=':/'` it gives me correct path `./file.php`

I only don't know what `$con` is. Maybe you have `dirname(dirname($content))` in your oryginal code and `$content = $_REQUEST['code'];` => `dirname(dirname($_REQUEST['code']))` => `dirname(dirname("/:"))` => `"\"`

Comment: $con was the client's PHP/HTML code.

But, hey bro, I solved the problem... but I really don't know how I did it. I just add an str_replace to my code before the headers, and suddenly everything went all right.

Comment: $con = str_replace("/", "!@%slash@%!", $con); and Poof! all the problems were gone. The thing that worries me is that i wrote that str_replace thing after the file_put_contents... which means that the code was already written in the file.